Input impedance of an op amp when sharing bias resistor across multiple op amps
This is a theoretical question more than it is a practical one, and perhaps a bit simple, but I cannot find a reliable answer. Let's say you have a simple op amp buffer like the one below:

Source: AMZFX - Basic Buffers
Given the value of R1 (1M), the input impedance for this op amp buffer is 1M, but what would happen to the input impedance if you were to have another non-inverting op amp in a similar configuration and connect both non-inverting inputs to a single, common 1M bias resistor (still R1 In this case)? Would the impedance of both op amps be halved (500K)? If so, does this principle extend to N number of op amps (would sharing a bias resistor across four op amp stages result in the input impedance of each stage being 250K, etc.)?

Do you want to short the +ve terminal of both the opamps? It is not clear...

@sai the supply connections would be the same for each op amp in this scenario, I'm just wondering what would happen to the input impedance of each op amp stage of they shared a common bias resistor.

@paraparabolic Are you looking for something like this?: schematic

Something like that configuration, or even having the op amp stages in series, just curious overall. Not looking to divide the input impedance in practice necessarily, but had wondered what would happen if you shared a common bias resistor (which had been difficult to find an answer for) as a sort of supposition.

you're confusing terms here, I'm afraid, @paraparabolic. The input impedance of this circuit is 1MΩ, regardless of how many opamps you connect. The input impedance of your opamp is in the Gigaohms or such, so that you can do that within an error that is negligible compared to all other errors (such as an 1 MΩ resistor not actually being exactly 1 MΩ). The opamp doesn't "care" about the input impedance, so asking whether you half it makes no sense.

Some op amps have a low enough input impedance that it could affect the equivalent input resistance, so you may have to include that in the calculation.  It would be the parallel resistance R1 plus the input resistance of all the op amps in parallel.

The opamp is assumed to have effectively infinite input impedance, so connecting additional opamps to the top of R1 does not change the impedance seen by the input signal.
But I'm not sure why you'd do that — they'd all be outputting the same signal.

Thanks for your answer! And yeah, this is really just my trying to understand the theoretical results of such a configuration. What would the impedance look like if the op amps that were sharing the bias resistor were in series (one after another) instead of in parallel?

I'm not sure why you're so stuck on "sharing a bias resistor". The concept doesn't make much sense. If you tried to do that with a series string, most of the amplifiers would have their outputs shorted to their inputs. For voltage followers specifically, it's completely unnecessary anyway -- the output of one amplifier is already biased correctly to drive the next. In general, each amplifier needs its own resistor if it's going to be processing a different signal.

It's not that I'm stuck on it, it's just that I'm curious, and it's a bit difficult to search for, so directly asking seemed like the best choice to learn. Thanks again!
